# shiny app for single cell cluster export issue

Tags: single-cell

I'm trying to create a shiny app for single cell data visualization and then label cells with genes till this step it works, the final step when I try to export cluster it is not exporting the desired cluster or i might be doing something wrong which Im not sure

This the code

```
library(Seurat)
library(BiocParallel)
library(reticulate)
library(Matrix)
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)

# Set the maximum file upload size to 3 GB
options(shiny.maxRequestSize = 3e+9)

# Define the UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Single-cell RNA-seq Analysis"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput("h5ad_file", "Upload H5AD File", accept = ".h5ad"),
      actionButton("run_button", "Run Analysis"),
      selectInput("gene_input", "Select Gene for Feature Plot:", choices = NULL),
      downloadButton("export_button", "Export Cluster")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("feature_plot")
    )
  )
)

# Define the server
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  # Function to perform the analysis
  performAnalysis <- function(h5ad_file) {
    sc <- import("scanpy")
    adata <- sc$read_h5ad(h5ad_file)
    
    counts <- t(adata$layers["counts"])
    colnames(counts) <- adata$obs_names$to_list()
    rownames(counts) <- adata$var_names$to_list()
    counts <- Matrix::Matrix(as.matrix(counts), sparse = TRUE)
    
    data <- t(adata$layers["winsorized"])
    colnames(data) <- adata$obs_names$to_list()
    rownames(data) <- adata$var_names$to_list()
    data <- Matrix::Matrix(as.matrix(data), sparse = TRUE)
    
    seurat <- CreateSeuratObject(counts)
    seurat <- SetAssayData(seurat, "data", data)
    seurat <- AddMetaData(seurat, adata$obs)
    
    seurat[["percent.mt"]] <- PercentageFeatureSet(seurat, pattern = "^MT[-\\.]")
    seurat <- NormalizeData(seurat)
    seurat <- FindVariableFeatures(seurat, nfeatures = 500)
    seurat <- ScaleData(seurat)
    seurat <- ScaleData(seurat, vars.to.regress = c("nFeature_RNA", "percent.mt"))
    seurat <- RunPCA(seurat, npcs = 50)
    seurat <- RunUMAP(seurat, dims = 1:20)
    seurat <- FindNeighbors(seurat, dims = 1:20)
    seurat <- FindClusters(seurat, resolution = 1)
    cl_markers <- FindAllMarkers(seurat, only.pos = TRUE, min.pct = 0.25, logfc.threshold = log(1.2))
    top_gene <- cl_markers %>% group_by(cluster) %>% top_n(n = 2, wt = avg_log2FC)
    
    return(seurat)
  }
  
  # Reactive value to store the Seurat object
  seurat_object <- reactiveVal(NULL)
  
  # Perform analysis when the Run Analysis button is clicked
  observeEvent(input$run_button, {
    req(input$h5ad_file)
    h5ad_file <- input$h5ad_file$datapath
    seurat <- performAnalysis(h5ad_file)
    seurat_object(seurat)
    
    # Update gene choices for feature plot
    gene_choices <- rownames(seurat@assays$RNA@counts)
    updateSelectInput(session, "gene_input", choices = gene_choices)
  })
  
  # Render the feature plot
  output$feature_plot <- renderPlot({
    seurat <- seurat_object()
    if (!is.null(seurat)) {
      gene <- input$gene_input
      FeaturePlot(seurat, features = gene, label = TRUE)
    }
  })
  
  # Export cluster when the Export Cluster button is clicked
  observeEvent(input$export_button, {
    seurat <- seurat_object()
    if (!is.null(seurat)) {
      cluster_data <- cbind(Cluster = seurat@meta.data$cluster, seurat@assays$RNA@counts)
      write.csv(cluster_data, "cluster.csv", row.names = TRUE)
      updateActionButton(session, "export_button", label = "Download Cluster", href = "cluster.csv")
    }
  })
  
  
  
  
  # Function to end the session
  endSession <- function() {
    stopApp()  # This will end the Shiny session and shut down the server
  }
  
  # Call the endSession function when the session ends (browser window closed)
  session$onSessionEnded(endSession)
}

# Run the Shiny app
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The **seurat** object which is generated its structure is like this

```
str(seurat)
Formal class 'Seurat' [package "SeuratObject"] with 13 slots
  ..@ assays      :List of 1
  .. ..$ RNA:Formal class 'Assay' [package "SeuratObject"] with 8 slots
  .. .. .. ..@ counts       :Formal class 'dgCMatrix' [package "Matrix"] with 6 slots
  .. .. .. .. .. ..@ i       : int [1:2238732] 29 73 80 148 163 184 186 227 229 230 ...
  .. .. .. .. .. ..@ p       : int [1:2639] 0 779 2131 3260 4220 4741 5522 6304 7094 7626 ...
  .. .. .. .. .. ..@ Dim     : int [1:2] 13714 2638
  .. .. .. .. .. ..@ Dimnames:List of 2
  .. .. .. .. .. .. ..$ : chr [1:13714] "AL627309.1" "AP006222.2" "RP11-206L10.2" "RP11-206L10.9" ...
  .. .. .. .. .. .. ..$ : chr [1:2638] "AAACATACAACCAC-1" "AAACATTGAGCTAC-1" "AAACATTGATCAGC-1" "AAACCGTGCTTCCG-1" ...
  .. .. .. .. .. ..@ x       : num [1:2238732] 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 41 1 1 ...
  .. .. .. .. .. ..@ factors : list()
  .. .. .. ..@ data         :Formal class 'dgCMatrix' [package "Matrix"] with 6 slots
  .. .. .. .. .. ..@ i       : int [1:2238732] 29 73 80 148 163 184 186 227 229 230 ...
  .. .. .. .. .. ..@ p       : int [1:2639] 0 779 2131 3260 4220 4741 5522 6304 7094 7626 ...
  .. .. .. .. .. ..@ Dim     : int [1:2] 13714 2638
  .. .. .. .. .. ..@ Dimnames:List of 2
  .. .. .. .. .. .. ..$ : chr [1:13714] "AL627309.1" "AP006222.2" "RP11-206L10.2" "RP11-206L10.9" ...
  .. .. .. .. .. .. ..$ : chr [1:2638] "AAACATACAACCAC-1" "AAACATTGAGCTAC-1" "AAACATTGATCAGC-1" "AAACCGTGCTTCCG-1" ...
  .. .. .. .. .. ..@ x       : num [1:2238732] 1.64 1.64 2.23 1.64 1.64 ...
  .. .. .. .. .. ..@ factors : list()
  .. .. .. ..@ scale.data   : num [1:500, 1:2638] 1.5265 -0.4982 -0.0324 -0.3129 -0.4631 ...
  .. .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. .. .. .. ..$ : chr [1:500] "MRPL20" "RER1" "TNFRSF9" "SRM" ...
  .. .. .. .. .. ..$ : chr [1:2638] "AAACATACAACCAC-1" "AAACATTGAGCTAC-1" "AAACATTGATCAGC-1" "AAACCGTGCTTCCG-1" ...
  .. .. .. ..@ key          : chr "rna_"
  .. .. .. ..@ assay.orig   : NULL
  .. .. .. ..@ var.features : chr [1:500] "PPBP" "LYZ" "S100A9" "IGLL5" ...
  .. .. .. ..@ meta.features:'data.frame':  13714 obs. of  5 variables:
  .. .. .. .. ..$ vst.mean                 : num [1:13714] 0.00341 0.00114 0.0019 0.00114 0.00682 ...
  .. .. .. .. ..$ vst.variance             : num [1:13714] 0.0034 0.00114 0.00189 0.00114 0.00678 ...
  .. .. .. .. ..$ vst.variance.expected    : num [1:13714] 0.00365 0.00114 0.00197 0.00114 0.00748 ...
  .. .. .. .. ..$ vst.variance.standardized: num [1:13714] 0.933 0.992 0.963 0.992 0.906 ...
  .. .. .. .. ..$ vst.variable             : logi [1:13714] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE ...
  .. .. .. ..@ misc         : list()
  ..@ meta.data   :'data.frame':    2638 obs. of  10 variables:
  .. ..$ orig.ident     : Factor w/ 1 level "SeuratProject": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  .. ..$ nCount_RNA     : num [1:2638] 2419 4903 3147 2639 980 ...
  .. ..$ nFeature_RNA   : int [1:2638] 779 1352 1129 960 521 781 782 790 532 550 ...
  .. ..$ n_genes        : num [1:2638] 781 1352 1131 960 522 ...
  .. ..$ percent_mito   : num [1:2638] 0.0302 0.0379 0.0089 0.0174 0.0122 ...
  .. ..$ n_counts       : num [1:2638] 2419 4903 3147 2639 980 ...
  .. ..$ louvain        : Factor w/ 8 levels "CD4 T cells",..: 1 3 1 2 5 4 4 4 1 6 ...
  .. ..$ percent.mt     : num [1:2638] 3.02 3.79 0.89 1.74 1.22 ...
  .. ..$ RNA_snn_res.1  : Factor w/ 8 levels "0","1","2","3",..: 1 3 1 6 4 1 5 5 5 6 ...
  .. ..$ seurat_clusters: Factor w/ 8 levels "0","1","2","3",..: 1 3 1 6 4 1 5 5 5 6 ...
  ..@ active.assay: chr "RNA"
  ..@ active.ident: Factor w/ 8 levels "0","1","2","3",..: 1 3 1 6 4 1 5 5 5 6 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:2638] "AAACATACAACCAC-1" "AAACATTGAGCTAC-1" "AAACATTGATCAGC-1" "AAACCGTGCTTCCG-1" ...
  ..@ graphs      :List of 2
  .. ..$ RNA_nn :Formal class 'Graph' [package "SeuratObject"] with 7 slots
  .. .. .. ..@ assay.used: chr "RNA"
  .. .. .. ..@ i         : int [1:52760] 0 102 187 274 457 833 1147 1503 1506 1550 ...
  .. .. .. ..@ p         : int [1:2639] 0 17 24 30 33 40 61 83 85 96 ...
  .. .. .. ..@ Dim       : int [1:2] 2638 2638
  .. .. .. ..@ Dimnames  :List of 2
  .. .. .. .. ..$ : chr [1:2638] "AAACATACAACCAC-1" "AAACATTGAGCTAC-1" "AAACATTGATCAGC-1" "AAACCGTGCTTCCG-1" ...
  .. .. .. .. ..$ : chr [1:2638] "AAACATACAACCAC-1" "AAACATTGAGCTAC-1" "AAACATTGATCAGC-1" "AAACCGTGCTTCCG-1" ...
  .. .. .. ..@ x         : num [1:52760] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  .. .. .. ..@ factors   : list()
  .. ..$ RNA_snn:Formal class 'Graph' [package "SeuratObject"] with 7 slots
  .. .. .. ..@ assay.used: chr "RNA"
  .. .. .. ..@ i         : int [1:245992] 0 69 102 172 187 189 248 274 276 315 ...
  .. .. .. ..@ p         : int [1:2639] 0 79 118 179 253 323 424 541 574 650 ...
  .. .. .. ..@ Dim       : int [1:2] 2638 2638
  .. .. .. ..@ Dimnames  :List of 2
  .. .. .. .. ..$ : chr [1:2638] "AAACATACAACCAC-1" "AAACATTGAGCTAC-1" "AAACATTGATCAGC-1" "AAACCGTGCTTCCG-1" ...
  .. .. .. .. ..$ : chr [1:2638] "AAACATACAACCAC-1" "AAACATTGAGCTAC-1" "AAACATTGATCAGC-1" "AAACCGTGCTTCCG-1" ...
  .. .. .. ..@ x         : num [1:245992] 1 0.0811 0.2903 0.1765 0.1765 ...
  .. .. .. ..@ factors   : list()
  ..@ neighbors   : list()
  ..@ reductions  :List of 2
  .. ..$ pca :Formal class 'DimReduc' [package "SeuratObject"] with 9 slots
  .. .. .. ..@ cell.embeddings           : num [1:2638, 1:50] -3.544 -5.892 -3.544 10.139 0.932 ...
  .. .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. .. .. .. ..$ : chr [1:2638] "AAACATACAACCAC-1" "AAACATTGAGCTAC-1" "AAACATTGATCAGC-1" "AAACCGTGCTTCCG-1" ...
  .. .. .. .. .. ..$ : chr [1:50] "PC_1" "PC_2" "PC_3" "PC_4" ...
  .. .. .. ..@ feature.loadings          : num [1:500, 1:50] 0.02701 0.16566 0.17077 -0.00786 -0.03674 ...
  .. .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. .. .. .. ..$ : chr [1:500] "PPBP" "LYZ" "S100A9" "IGLL5" ...
  .. .. .. .. .. ..$ : chr [1:50] "PC_1" "PC_2" "PC_3" "PC_4" ...
  .. .. .. ..@ feature.loadings.projected: num[0 , 0 ] 
  .. .. .. ..@ assay.used                : chr "RNA"
  .. .. .. ..@ global                    : logi FALSE
  .. .. .. ..@ stdev                     : num [1:50] 5 3.39 3.2 2.78 1.94 ...
  .. .. .. ..@ key                       : chr "PC_"
  .. .. .. ..@ jackstraw                 :Formal class 'JackStrawData' [package "SeuratObject"] with 4 slots
  .. .. .. .. .. ..@ empirical.p.values     : num[0 , 0 ] 
  .. .. .. .. .. ..@ fake.reduction.scores  : num[0 , 0 ] 
  .. .. .. .. .. ..@ empirical.p.values.full: num[0 , 0 ] 
  .. .. .. .. .. ..@ overall.p.values       : num[0 , 0 ] 
  .. .. .. ..@ misc                      :List of 1
  .. .. .. .. ..$ total.variance: num 457
  .. ..$ umap:Formal class 'DimReduc' [package "SeuratObject"] with 9 slots
  .. .. .. ..@ cell.embeddings           : num [1:2638, 1:2] -3.44 -7.94 -1.77 8.79 -1.51 ...
  .. .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "scaled:center")= num [1:2] 1.64 -1.3
  .. .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. .. .. .. ..$ : chr [1:2638] "AAACATACAACCAC-1" "AAACATTGAGCTAC-1" "AAACATTGATCAGC-1" "AAACCGTGCTTCCG-1" ...
  .. .. .. .. .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "UMAP_1" "UMAP_2"
  .. .. .. ..@ feature.loadings          : num[0 , 0 ] 
  .. .. .. ..@ feature.loadings.projected: num[0 , 0 ] 
  .. .. .. ..@ assay.used                : chr "RNA"
  .. .. .. ..@ global                    : logi TRUE
  .. .. .. ..@ stdev                     : num(0) 
  .. .. .. ..@ key                       : chr "UMAP_"
  .. .. .. ..@ jackstraw                 :Formal class 'JackStrawData' [package "SeuratObject"] with 4 slots
  .. .. .. .. .. ..@ empirical.p.values     : num[0 , 0 ] 
  .. .. .. .. .. ..@ fake.reduction.scores  : num[0 , 0 ] 
  .. .. .. .. .. ..@ empirical.p.values.full: num[0 , 0 ] 
  .. .. .. .. .. ..@ overall.p.values       : num[0 , 0 ] 
  .. .. .. ..@ misc                      : list()
  ..@ images      : list()
  ..@ project.name: chr "SeuratProject"
  ..@ misc        : list()
  ..@ version     :Classes 'package_version', 'numeric_version'  hidden list of 1
  .. ..$ : int [1:3] 4 1 3
  ..@ commands    :List of 7
  .. ..$ NormalizeData.RNA       :Formal class 'SeuratCommand' [package "SeuratObject"] with 5 slots
  .. .. .. ..@ name       : chr "NormalizeData.RNA"
  .. .. .. ..@ time.stamp : POSIXct[1:1], format: "2023-05-21 03:58:21"
  .. .. .. ..@ assay.used : chr "RNA"
  .. .. .. ..@ call.string: chr "NormalizeData(seurat)"
  .. .. .. ..@ params     :List of 5
  .. .. .. .. ..$ assay               : chr "RNA"
  .. .. .. .. ..$ normalization.method: chr "LogNormalize"
  .. .. .. .. ..$ scale.factor        : num 10000
  .. .. .. .. ..$ margin              : num 1
  .. .. .. .. ..$ verbose             : logi TRUE
  .. ..$ FindVariableFeatures.RNA:Formal class 'SeuratCommand' [package "SeuratObject"] with 5 slots
  .. .. .. ..@ name       : chr "FindVariableFeatures.RNA"
  .. .. .. ..@ time.stamp : POSIXct[1:1], format: "2023-05-21 03:58:22"
  .. .. .. ..@ assay.used : chr "RNA"
  .. .. .. ..@ call.string: chr "FindVariableFeatures(seurat, nfeatures = 500)"
  .. .. .. ..@ params     :List of 12
  .. .. .. .. ..$ assay              : chr "RNA"
  .. .. .. .. ..$ selection.method   : chr "vst"
  .. .. .. .. ..$ loess.span         : num 0.3
  .. .. .. .. ..$ clip.max           : chr "auto"
  .. .. .. .. ..$ mean.function      :function (mat, display_progress)  
  .. .. .. .. ..$ dispersion.function:function (mat, display_progress)  
  .. .. .. .. ..$ num.bin            : num 20
  .. .. .. .. ..$ binning.method     : chr "equal_width"
  .. .. .. .. ..$ nfeatures          : num 500
  .. .. .. .. ..$ mean.cutoff        : num [1:2] 0.1 8
  .. .. .. .. ..$ dispersion.cutoff  : num [1:2] 1 Inf
  .. .. .. .. ..$ verbose            : logi TRUE
  .. ..$ ScaleData.RNA           :Formal class 'SeuratCommand' [package "SeuratObject"] with 5 slots
  .. .. .. ..@ name       : chr "ScaleData.RNA"
  .. .. .. ..@ time.stamp : POSIXct[1:1], format: "2023-05-21 03:58:23"
  .. .. .. ..@ assay.used : chr "RNA"
  .. .. .. ..@ call.string: chr [1:2] "ScaleData(seurat, vars.to.regress = c(\"nFeature_RNA\", " "    \"percent.mt\"))"
  .. .. .. ..@ params     :List of 11
  .. .. .. .. ..$ features          : chr [1:500] "PPBP" "LYZ" "S100A9" "IGLL5" ...
  .. .. .. .. ..$ assay             : chr "RNA"
  .. .. .. .. ..$ vars.to.regress   : chr [1:2] "nFeature_RNA" "percent.mt"
  .. .. .. .. ..$ model.use         : chr "linear"
  .. .. .. .. ..$ use.umi           : logi FALSE
  .. .. .. .. ..$ do.scale          : logi TRUE
  .. .. .. .. ..$ do.center         : logi TRUE
  .. .. .. .. ..$ scale.max         : num 10
  .. .. .. .. ..$ block.size        : num 1000
  .. .. .. .. ..$ min.cells.to.block: num 2638
  .. .. .. .. ..$ verbose           : logi TRUE
  .. ..$ RunPCA.RNA              :Formal class 'SeuratCommand' [package "SeuratObject"] with 5 slots
  .. .. .. ..@ name       : chr "RunPCA.RNA"
  .. .. .. ..@ time.stamp : POSIXct[1:1], format: "2023-05-21 03:58:25"
  .. .. .. ..@ assay.used : chr "RNA"
  .. .. .. ..@ call.string: chr "RunPCA(seurat, npcs = 50)"
  .. .. .. ..@ params     :List of 10
  .. .. .. .. ..$ assay          : chr "RNA"
  .. .. .. .. ..$ npcs           : num 50
  .. .. .. .. ..$ rev.pca        : logi FALSE
  .. .. .. .. ..$ weight.by.var  : logi TRUE
  .. .. .. .. ..$ verbose        : logi TRUE
  .. .. .. .. ..$ ndims.print    : int [1:5] 1 2 3 4 5
  .. .. .. .. ..$ nfeatures.print: num 30
  .. .. .. .. ..$ reduction.name : chr "pca"
  .. .. .. .. ..$ reduction.key  : chr "PC_"
  .. .. .. .. ..$ seed.use       : num 42
  .. ..$ RunUMAP.RNA.pca         :Formal class 'SeuratCommand' [package "SeuratObject"] with 5 slots
  .. .. .. ..@ name       : chr "RunUMAP.RNA.pca"
  .. .. .. ..@ time.stamp : POSIXct[1:1], format: "2023-05-21 03:58:35"
  .. .. .. ..@ assay.used : chr "RNA"
  .. .. .. ..@ call.string: chr "RunUMAP(seurat, dims = 1:20)"
  .. .. .. ..@ params     :List of 26
  .. .. .. .. ..$ dims                : int [1:20] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
  .. .. .. .. ..$ reduction           : chr "pca"
  .. .. .. .. ..$ assay               : chr "RNA"
  .. .. .. .. ..$ slot                : chr "data"
  .. .. .. .. ..$ umap.method         : chr "uwot"
  .. .. .. .. ..$ return.model        : logi FALSE
  .. .. .. .. ..$ n.neighbors         : int 30
  .. .. .. .. ..$ n.components        : int 2
  .. .. .. .. ..$ metric              : chr "cosine"
  .. .. .. .. ..$ learning.rate       : num 1
  .. .. .. .. ..$ min.dist            : num 0.3
  .. .. .. .. ..$ spread              : num 1
  .. .. .. .. ..$ set.op.mix.ratio    : num 1
  .. .. .. .. ..$ local.connectivity  : int 1
  .. .. .. .. ..$ repulsion.strength  : num 1
  .. .. .. .. ..$ negative.sample.rate: int 5
  .. .. .. .. ..$ uwot.sgd            : logi FALSE
  .. .. .. .. ..$ seed.use            : int 42
  .. .. .. .. ..$ angular.rp.forest   : logi FALSE
  .. .. .. .. ..$ densmap             : logi FALSE
  .. .. .. .. ..$ dens.lambda         : num 2
  .. .. .. .. ..$ dens.frac           : num 0.3
  .. .. .. .. ..$ dens.var.shift      : num 0.1
  .. .. .. .. ..$ verbose             : logi TRUE
  .. .. .. .. ..$ reduction.name      : chr "umap"
  .. .. .. .. ..$ reduction.key       : chr "UMAP_"
  .. ..$ FindNeighbors.RNA.pca   :Formal class 'SeuratCommand' [package "SeuratObject"] with 5 slots
  .. .. .. ..@ name       : chr "FindNeighbors.RNA.pca"
  .. .. .. ..@ time.stamp : POSIXct[1:1], format: "2023-05-21 03:58:35"
  .. .. .. ..@ assay.used : chr "RNA"
  .. .. .. ..@ call.string: chr "FindNeighbors(seurat, dims = 1:20)"
  .. .. .. ..@ params     :List of 17
  .. .. .. .. ..$ reduction      : chr "pca"
  .. .. .. .. ..$ dims           : int [1:20] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
  .. .. .. .. ..$ assay          : chr "RNA"
  .. .. .. .. ..$ k.param        : num 20
  .. .. .. .. ..$ return.neighbor: logi FALSE
  .. .. .. .. ..$ compute.SNN    : logi TRUE
  .. .. .. .. ..$ prune.SNN      : num 0.0667
  .. .. .. .. ..$ nn.method      : chr "annoy"
  .. .. .. .. ..$ n.trees        : num 50
  .. .. .. .. ..$ annoy.metric   : chr "euclidean"
  .. .. .. .. ..$ nn.eps         : num 0
  .. .. .. .. ..$ verbose        : logi TRUE
  .. .. .. .. ..$ force.recalc   : logi FALSE
  .. .. .. .. ..$ do.plot        : logi FALSE
  .. .. .. .. ..$ graph.name     : chr [1:2] "RNA_nn" "RNA_snn"
  .. .. .. .. ..$ l2.norm        : logi FALSE
  .. .. .. .. ..$ cache.index    : logi FALSE
  .. ..$ FindClusters            :Formal class 'SeuratCommand' [package "SeuratObject"] with 5 slots
  .. .. .. ..@ name       : chr "FindClusters"
  .. .. .. ..@ time.stamp : POSIXct[1:1], format: "2023-05-21 03:58:36"
  .. .. .. ..@ assay.used : chr "RNA"
  .. .. .. ..@ call.string: chr "FindClusters(seurat, resolution = 1)"
  .. .. .. ..@ params     :List of 10
  .. .. .. .. ..$ graph.name      : chr "RNA_snn"
  .. .. .. .. ..$ modularity.fxn  : num 1
  .. .. .. .. ..$ resolution      : num 1
  .. .. .. .. ..$ method          : chr "matrix"
  .. .. .. .. ..$ algorithm       : num 1
  .. .. .. .. ..$ n.start         : num 10
  .. .. .. .. ..$ n.iter          : num 10
  .. .. .. .. ..$ random.seed     : num 0
  .. .. .. .. ..$ group.singletons: logi TRUE
  .. .. .. .. ..$ verbose         : logi TRUE
  ..@ tools       : list()
```

My objective is

- Generate feature plot
- Then label the cells based on only variable genes,right now I see all the genes I would like to only label based on top genes which I'm storing at `top_gene` but Im not sure how to incorporate it instead of every genes which I now see in my drop down menu
- The after labelling cells i want to export the labelled cluster as csv file

What Now Im getting is html file which not what I want

Any help or suggestion is really helpful

**UPDATE**
The right function I have to use is this `FetchData()` but Im not sure how to pass the gene which i choose to label the cells and use the same gene as input for exporting cluster